# No of buckets in hive table

Tags: hive

what is the formula for bucketing?
concept behind it and how can we get that  modulous 3 in that formula?

hi, I am try to give no. of bucket in my hive table i am not get how to give nummber of bucket in my hive table

f(x)%3

Answer (score 1):

Bucketing is to distribute large number rows evenly to get a good performance. Number of buckets should be determined by number of rows and future growth in count.

The function that calculates number of rows in each bucket is

```
hash_function(bucket_column)  mod num_of_buckets
```

So, using this complex function, hive creates a fixed width out put and then distributes the data based on that.
Referring to below picture, four input rows are generating three outputs `01,02,04` - which means, if you have three buckets, first bucket will contain `Lisa Smith`, second will contain `Joh Smith and Sandra Dee`, and third one will contain `Sam Doe`.

[image]

<sup>Image from [Wikipedia: Hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), released into the public domain</sup>

If bucket_column is an `INT`, then hash func output is somewhat even and distribution is uniform.
But if its a string or date, the hash output is not uniform which can make different rows to be clubbed together in a bucket. You can refer to above example - where `John Smith` and `Sandra Dee` are generating output value `02` and they will go into same bucket. So, for string, date, or any other data type(even bigint), its difficult to ensure even distribution and you have to trust hive for this.

Now, while creating number of buckets considering existing data and future growth,
if you have 500 thousand rows and you want to split it in 3 buckets, it should be fine. But if you have 100million rows, then making 3 bucket wont make much sense, so go for 1000 buckets. Also please note, creating many buckets will degrade loading data into the table.